# Returning a Sequelize Result thats Async before doing next steps

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

I have my function that does all of my logic and then I want to get a count of all Products. I could do a `.then()` but I don't want it nested.
This query I want to be ran before anything else too. How can I run this and get the result in a variable first. I tried async await but it still hops to next section before finishing.

I also tried Promise.resolve

```
// initial code here 

  let productCount = Promise.resolve( Product.count({
    where: {
      title: {
        $like: '%'+searchTerm+'%'
      },
    },
  }).then(result => {
    return result
  })

)

// get product count
// do some logic

// my next query which I do results in .then
```

Comment: No matter what you try, `productCount` is going to remain a `Promise`. Just move your sequential logic into `.then()` and rename `result` to `productCount`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Even if I split this up into another function I can't do anything about it? All of my logic will have to go into a nested then()?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've quite understood you correctly, but if all you want to do is wait for Product.count() to finish before moving on then you could do something like the following:

```
async function productCount(searchTerm) {
  let productCount = await Product.count({
    where: {
      title: {
        $like: '%'+searchTerm+'%'
      },
    },
  })
  return productCount
}
```

When you are calling productCount() you will also have to use await and put 'async' in front of the calling function's name e.g.:

```
async function callingFunction() {
  ...    
  let productCount = await productCount(searchTerm)
  // do something with productCount
}
```